# Unresolved external symbol using Direct2D

Tags: c++, linker-errors, unresolved-external, direct2d

I am trying to download and build the 'WIC Image Viewer usign Direct2D' from [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/win7wicsamples), but when I build my solution, I am slapped with 56 errors that look like:

> - Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CoUninitialize@0 referenced in function _wWinMain@16   WICViewerD2D.obj
> - Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DispatchMessageW@4 referenced in function _wWinMain@16 WICViewerD2D.obj
> - Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__TranslateMessage@4 referenced in function _wWinMain@16 WICViewerD2D.obj

and so on. Surely this is something in my Visual Studio settings, because isn't this code supposed to work out of the box? I have Windows SDK v7.0 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could most likely mean that your directory settings in the Visual Studio project aren't correctly set.
For VS2008, go to Tools-->Options-->Projects and Solutions-->VC++ Directories and set the appropriate include file path and library file path.

Make sure you referenced the correct library files by stating their names in Project-->Properties-->Linker-->Input-->"Additional Dependencies".

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had added the wrong folder for the libraries.